# Swap cognito user pool in aws amplify authentication

Tags: amazon-cognito, aws-amplify

I am authenticating my site's users with AWS Amplify and Cognito user pools. I needed to create a new user pool. How do I update the cognito pool name/id/(whatever parameters are necessary for this update) in AWS Amplify? Or do I need to update these parameters in my vuejs application? Cheers.

Comment: Okay, I think I found the setting. In AWS AppSync > Settings > Default authorization mode > Select a user pool.

Comment: However, simply selecting the new user pool in this dropdown did not do the trick. When a new user signs up for my site, they are still added to the previous user pool.

Comment: Or is it impossible to update the Cognito user pool. Maybe I need to launch a new AWS Amplify project?

Comment: Linking this conversation I had with AWS Amplify support. https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-adminui/issues/252